# Renaming shapefiles with prefix while running arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

I'm fairly new to the arcpy world. I am trying to create a script in 10.0 that will load a dataset (file geodatabase) into ArcSDE and rename the feature classes with a prefix, i.e. San_Diego_Bay -> AJ_San_Diego_Bay. My script is below and is very basic for loading shapefiles into a geodatabase. I would like to load a file geodatabase into an ArcSDE Feature Dataset. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "Z:/Data/Test_arcpy"

# Set local variables
inFeatures = ["Atlantic_Offshore_Areas.shp", "C_C_mauritania.shp", "E_Class.shp", "San_Diego_Bay.shp"]
outLocation = "Z:/Data/Test_arcpy/test_two_arcpy.gdb"

# Execute TableToGeodatabase
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation)
```

Answer (score 3):

The attached script should help.  The general idea here is to loop through your directory with a `for` loop and use [Feature Class to Feature class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000020000000) to copy the shapefiles to a FGDB.  When you define the output name, you have to strip the ".shp" extension or else you will receive errors.

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set workspace
env.workspace = "Z:/Data/Test_arcpy"
Dir = env.workspace

# Set local variables
out_path = "Z:/Data/Test_arcpy/test_two_arcpy.gdb"

# List the shapefiles in your directory
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# Alternatively, create your own subset
#fclist = ["Atlantic_Offshore_Areas.shp", "C_C_mauritania.shp", "E_Class.shp", "San_Diego_Bay.shp"]

for fc in fclist:

    # Manipulate the string
    name = "AJ_" + str(fc.rsplit(".",1)[0])

     # Execute FeatureClassToFeatureClass
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, out_path, name)
```